# React Native Firebase push notification

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification

I have a requirement to automatically send push notifications to my application when new data is inserted into firebase.
Is there any way to do so ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Firebase Functions as a middleware function for sending push notifications via FCM to the device If the database value is changed.

Adding an example from my [**FirebaseDBtoFCMFunction**](https://github.com/rufat/FirebaseDBtoFCMFunction) repo.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database
    .ref('/users/{user_id}') // Put your path here with the params.
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
        try {
            const { after } = change;
            const { _data } = after;
            const { deviceToken } = _data.receiver; // Always send the device token within the data entry.
            
            if(!deviceToken) return;
            
            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: 'Notification',
                    body: `FCM notification triggered!`
                },
                data: context.params // Passing the path params along with the notification to the device. [optional]
            };
            
            return await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload);
        } catch (ex) {
            return console.error('Error:', ex.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: @ufatmammadli Thanks for the help. I am new in React Native, Can you please suggest a video tutorial for this ? Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I think these videos will help you; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rERRuBjxJ80, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6jMKQ9zo-o, and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NybmemQxdts. Please accept my answer If it did help. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am looking into it!

Comment: npm run deploy gives an error
error    Delete `··` 
error    Replace `············const·{·after·` with `······const·{after`
Replace `············const·{·_data·` with `······const·{_data`

Comment: Please make sure you installed the Firebase CLI (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) and inserted your project ID into the deploy command (in package.json).

Comment: I have already installed the FIrebase CLI but how to insert project ID into the the deploy command ?

Comment: Is this the correct way of adding project_id in functions/package.json
{
"scripts": {
"deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
"project_id": "<my_project_id>",
}
}

Beacause I am getting the same error.

Comment: You need to authenticate your account in Firebase CLI, choose your project, and then add the project ID into the deploy command which I wrote a placeholder like <YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE> (replace it with your actual ID). Try it again.

Comment: Can you please take a look into this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63240948/deploying-firebase-functions-gives-error-insert-prettier-prettier-delete

Answer (score 0):

Inside your application add child_change (valueChanged) or child_add event for specific database location than when it changes, it will fired.
[From doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data).

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
        .GetReference("Leaders").OrderByChild("score")
        .ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
    }

    void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
      if (args.DatabaseError != null) {
        Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
      }
      // Do something with the data in args.Snapshot
    }
```

For nodejs [value listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events)