# Deploying Firebase functions gives error "Insert `⏎` prettier/prettier" Delete '.' prettier/prettier

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am trying Firebase functions in my React Native Project. I followed the example at rnfirebase.io site and when I run the command npm run deploy it gave the error: 20:4  error  Insert `⏎`  prettier/prettier.

Then I pressed ⏎ at line 20 and it is working fine.

Later I copied a code from GitHub and it is also giving the same like errors. By following the errors I get some other errors. I don't know why I am getting these errors.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the Firebase Functions' project folder from the React project's root folder. If this still happens, please provide your code for review.